# When submitting is done perfectly even if errors come out

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, mat-input, mat-error

I have a form, with a minimum of characters and a maximum, the problem is that if the minimum is 2 characters and I put one I get the mat-error but when giving save it lets you save it with only one character.

```
 <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput #input1 maxlength="300" minlength="2"
                placeholder="Nombre"
               formControlName="name">
        <mat-hint align="end">{{input1.value?.length || 0}}/300</mat-hint>
        <mat-error>
           Minimo 2 caracteres máximo 300
        </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

The save button:

```
 <button  class="mat-raised-button mat-primary"  (click)="save()">Save</button>
```

The save function:

```
    save() {
    this.dialogRef.close(this.form.value);
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkjrsd-8flxvt

Comment: use form submit action

Comment: use formcontrol for the input.

Comment: I did it with submit action and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Form submit

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="save()" class="example-form">
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput #input1 maxlength="300" minlength="2"
            placeholder="Nombre"
           formControlName="name">
    <mat-hint align="end">{{input1.value?.length || 0}}/300</mat-hint>
    <mat-error>
        Minimo 2 caracteres máximo 300
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<button type="submit"> save</button>
```

In **component.ts**

```
save(){
  if(this.form.valid){
  console.log('saved')
  }
  else{
     console.log('invalid form')
  }
}
```

example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkjrsd)

[image]

Comment: I have tried it and keep sending me the form without validating it

Comment: just now updated code with example stackblitz. have a try and let me know

Comment: really?? but it is woking perfectly and i have updated the screenshot of result. yes you can edit the stackblitz and fork it after changes

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkjrsd-ycdfk1 HAVE A LOOK AT THIS EXAMPLE.  You have mentioned Required validator for id property but it wasnt using anywhere in html

Answer (score 0):

Validation should be in form control. You have to remove from HTML `maxlength="300" minlength="2"` and set form validation in form group like:

.ts

```
formGroup = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', [Validators.maxLength(300), Validators.minLength(2), Validators.required])
  });
```

.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput #input1 placeholder="Nombre" formControlName="name">
        <mat-hint align="end">{{input1.value?.length || 0}}/300</mat-hint>
        <mat-error>
           Minimo 2 caracteres máximo 300
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!formGroup.valid">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It stays deactivated all the time even if you enter it correctly